# todos sorting in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sorting

I am interested in a question about todos sorting in typescript
imagine that when choosing a sorting method, the sort function is called for tasks

there is an interface Todo

```
interface ITodo {
  title: string
  body: string
  id: number
  completed: boolean
}
```

the todos array itself

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<ITodo[]>([])
```

Sorting is selected using the select tag
if necessary, this is what the component looks like

```
<Select
    value={filter.sort}
    onChange={(selectedSort) => setFilter({ ...filter, sort: selectedSort })}
    options={[
       { value: 'title', name: 'By tilte' },
       { value: 'body', name: 'By body' }
    ]}
    defaultValue='Sorting'
/>
```

problematic function of sorting todos

```
const sortedTodos = useMemo(() => {
    if (sort)
        return [...todos].sort((a:ITodo, b:ITodo) => a[sort].localeCompare(b[sort]));            
    return todos;
}, [sort, todos]);
```

for example, if I pass the current string here for the selected sorting method, then everything works.Like this.

```
const sortedTodos = useMemo(() => {
    if (sort)
        return [...todos].sort((a:ITodo, b:ITodo) => a['title'].localeCompare(b['title']));            
    return todos;
}, [sort, todos]);
```

error:

> The element is implicitly of type "any", since an expression of type "string" cannot be used for indexing of type "Todo".
> An index signature with a parameter of type "string" was not found in the "ITodo" type.

[CodeSandBox](https://github.com/dimitriev01/Todos.git)

Comment: can you create codeSandbox for the same so I can help you with this?

Comment: I added codeSandbox